# Backstage structure and organization

Tags: spotify, backstage

I'm struggling to find out how to organize different type of resources in Backstage. I want to make backstage for company where we need to track following resources:

- Templates. To quickly bootstrap ready code
- Libraries. Simple npm package which will be used in projects. Just a link to github repository and documentation
- Projects. Company has many projects. Each project has separate github organization and repositories inside. I'd like to list all projects in Backstage including information about them like link to github organization, repositories, documentation, etc

I have no problems with templates, because backstage has a good documentation about that, but I don't understand what's the right way to register libraries. Backstage has kind `Component`, but I'm not sure whether is right way to use it for libraries.
And I have no idea how to handle projects part. How can I connect github organizations and list all available projects with linking to github organization.

Could someone just point me out to any kind of documentation or examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Component` is indeed the right kind of Entity to hold a Library. A `library` is a particular `type` of Component (other `type`s are `website` and `service`) - see docs [here](https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-catalog/descriptor-format#spectype-required).

Depending on what a Project really *is*, Backstage may or may not be an appropriate tool to manage it. If a Project is a chunk of work, with tasks, deliverables, and deadlines, then it's not really within Backstage's remit - Backstage aims to catalog Software entities, and a Project (in that sense) is something that's completed *with* Software, not a thing that *is* Software. However, if you're using the word Project to describe a collection of related Services and Resources that together accomplish a particular goal - a sort-of "higher-level service" - then that fits the description of a [System](https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-catalog/system-model#system) or, possibly, a [Domain](https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-catalog/system-model#domain).

Comment: It should be noted that you don't `have` to use Backstage's domain model. It is possible to create a new entity processor that maps exactly your company domain model. I find the cognitive overhead of mental mapping is too much. The drawback is that some plugins reference the catalog default domain model and those you may need to bring in partially into your codebase. BUT the good thing is that the catalog plugins are built to support this. https://github.com/backstage/backstage/blob/ae28f1266cdfd007d32ee78afa9624995ecd3985/docs/features/software-catalog/extending-the-model.md?plain=1#L467